# How to get the default audio stream type?

Tags: android, audio

I'm using `AudioManager.adjustSuggestedStreamVolume(int direction, int suggestedStreamType, int flags)` with `suggestedStreamType` set to `AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE`. What this does is it decides what stream type (`STREAM_RING`, `STREAM_MEDIA` etc) is the most relevant for a given context (my app) and adjusts its volume accordingly. My question is, is there a way to "resolve" what exactly is the most relevant stream in a given context?

I've been searching through the Android source code, there is a method `AudioService.getActiveStreamType(int suggestedStreamType)` which does exactly what I want, but it's marked private so I can't use it in my app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If this is all for adjusting the stream volume in your app, you're best off manually setting it during creation with:

```
    activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

(Or any other stream type)
and modifying that appropriate stream therein.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that, however I don't want to hardcode any given stream, I just want to figure out what the system thinks is the appropriate and relevant stream within a given context. I actually tried to simplify it when asking a question, which might have been a bad idea... I'm not really making an app, I'm actually trying to modify a part of the Android core (more specifically, `android.policy.jar`). So I can't afford to have anything hardcoded.